# When using uuid in pivot table it return the uuid with repeated id how this thing happen?

Tags: php, laravel, uuid

i was using webpatser/laravel-uuid. to generate uuid into my pivot table, it works fine but the problem is the generated string was being repeated every time loop is perform i don't know how deal with this..

**Controller:**

```
 $data=$request->all();
        foreach($data['batch_id'] as $batch){
        $batch = Batch::find($batch);
        $lead = $data['lead_id'];
        $batch->lead()->attach($lead,["uuid" => Uuid::generate()]);

        $batch_leads = new batch_lead;
        $batch_leads->batch_id=$request->input('batch_id');
        $batch_leads->lead_id=$request->input('lead_id');
        $batch_leads = json_encode($data, true);
```

**Model:**

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    self::creating(function ($model) {
        $model->uuid = (string) Uuid::generate();
    });
}

public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'uuid';
}
```

Database Image:[image]

Comment: try this `Uuid::generate()->string`, if that didn't work then try `Uuid::generate(4)->string;` Also check this https://github.com/ramsey/uuid/issues/80#issuecomment-135478704

Comment: Still not working bro, hehe does jason has nothing to do with this?